# MIPS randomized word scrambler

Tags: string, assembly, random, mips, permutation

I am trying to write code that uses the MARS (my MIPS simulator) pseudorandom number generator to pick a random char in the string, take it out of memory and into a register, and replace that char in memory with an asterisk, '*'.

So far, it only scrambles part of the word, and it's driving me insane. I can't find what in this code isn't working. I don't even need a direct answer, just hints/tips would be SO helpful.

Here is the code:

```
#this loop extracts a char at random from a string in memory, stores it in a register, and replaces the char in the string with an asterisk '*'

.data

.align 2
string0: .ascii "Tyler\n"

.align 2
endString: .asciiz "Loop completed!\n"
.align 2
scrambleString: .asciiz


.text

#counter
li $t0, 5

#pointer to string0
la $s0, string0




loop2:

#is counter = 0? go to loop3 if so
beq $t0, $0, loop3

#seed & prepare randomized number generator
li $v0, 30 
syscall

li $v0, 40 #sets seed
syscall

#generates random number in $a0, with the coUnter $t0 being the upper bound
addi $a1, $t0, 1
li $v0, 42
syscall


#add STRING POINTER by random number in $a0, store this new address in $t1
#addi $a0, $a0, 1
add $t1, $s0, $a0
#srlv $t1, $s0, $a0

#isolates that bytesized char, puts it into $t2
lbu $t2, ($t1)
#beq $t2, 0x5c, loop2

#replaces char in original string with "*"
li $t3, 0x2a
sb $t3, ($t1)

beq $t1, $t3, loop2
#decrement counter
addi $t0, $t0, -1

#loop return
j loop2


loop3:
la $a0, string0
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: I have no knowledge of MIPS asm at all and do not know calling conventions used by syscall, but are you sure the $t0 and other temporary registers are preserved during syscall?

Answer (score 0):

1. You are resetting the random number seed on every iteration of
   your loop (loop2:).
2. Syscalls 40 and 42 each take 2 parameters which should be in `$a0` and
   `$a1`. See [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html).
3. The temporary registers `$t0,...,$t9` get altered by each
   `syscall`. You should be using the callee saved registers
   `$s0,...$s8` instead.